# Mongo ID to Meteor Mongo ID

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am writing a migration. I load a collection by mongodb because the collection definition has been deleted. I decompose data into SimpleSchema collections. I can not resave Mongo ObjectID because it is invalid. I tried the following variant. But it creates new. It can not recreate it.

```js
const meteorID = (_id) => new Mongo.ObjectID(_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Meteor's Mongo ID is inherently different from Mongo DB, so they're not interchangeable.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/2d41716645c75c5bc2ef37f306ef87c00b982d16/packages/mongo-id/id.js#L8

```
MongoID._looksLikeObjectID = str => str.length === 24 && str.match(/^[0-9a-f]*$/);

MongoID.ObjectID = class ObjectID {
  constructor (hexString) {
    //random-based impl of Mongo ObjectID
    if (hexString) {
      hexString = hexString.toLowerCase();
      if (!MongoID._looksLikeObjectID(hexString)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID');
      }
      // meant to work with _.isEqual(), which relies on structural equality
      this._str = hexString;
    } else {
      this._str = Random.hexString(24);
    }
  }

  equals(other) {
    return other instanceof MongoID.ObjectID &&
    this.valueOf() === other.valueOf();
  }

  toString() {
    return `ObjectID("${this._str}")`;
  }

  clone() {
    return new MongoID.ObjectID(this._str);
  }

  typeName() {
    return 'oid';
  }

  getTimestamp() {
    return Number.parseInt(this._str.substr(0, 8), 16);
  }

  valueOf() {
    return this._str;
  }

  toJSONValue() {
    return this.valueOf();
  }

  toHexString() {
    return this.valueOf();
  }

}
```

While Mongo's version:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/
https://github.com/williamkapke/bson-objectid

Comment: As a sidenote, they are one-side interchangeable: the Meteor Mongo Id hex string is the same length as the native Mongo ID. Therefore you need to "extract" the hex String from the mongo id, which you can then use to save as _id value. The Meteor  [Mongo Collections](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection) constructorsupport this via the `idGeneration` option.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo.ObjectID does not suggest Mongo ObjectID. It suggests only string or nothing.